# Install software on azure VM

Tags: azure

Is it possible to install softwares on a windows VM as and when they are created in a particular subscription? The actual need is to install endpoint protection software and vulnerability assessment tools onto the windows VMs every time a new one is deployed, all should happen without a admin triggering the installs.

Answer (score 0):

A VM extension will do what you need here. There are pre-built ones for some endpoint protection providers, alternatively you could script the install  and deploy it as a custom script extension. Extensions can be associated upon creation of the VM or added later, and can be deployed from the portal, powershell or an ARM template.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/features-windows

Answer (score -3):

please check this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment it shall answer your question.